# Web browser with no title / windows bars

Tags: browser, client, windowless

I've been looking into this for awhile now as I have created a client I would love to be able to run in a separate window (In a similar design to the Blizzard launcher or the old Ijji reactor). I was wondering if this was possible. Last week I created a web browser within Visual Basic but I was not happy with the final result at the bars where still stationed around the window. Any helpful tips or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify language, so you get it in c#. This might work. Starts chrome in app mode. here is the argument list

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

```
       url = "--app=http://google.com";
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

        if (pname.Length == 0) 
        {
            chrome = false;
        }
        else // if chrome is running
        {
            if (!chrome) 
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                process.Start();
                //Process.Start("chrome", url);
            }

            chrome = true;
        }
```

Comment: How/What do I need to run this script?

Comment: You put it in a application.

Comment: in javascript you can do this window.open(url,'myWin','width=500,height=300,left=20,top=20,toolbar=No,location=No,scrollbars=no,status=No,resizable=no,fullscreen=No');  NewWindow.focus();